# How do I use date(time) arithmetic in a sqlalchemy relationship?

Tags: python, date, datetime, sqlalchemy

I have something that looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

metadata = sa.MetaData(schema='myschema')
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


class MyThing(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'thing'

     ...
     id = sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True)

     recent_things = sa.orm.relationship(
         'OtherThing',
         primaryjoin="and(MyThing.id==OtherThing.thing_id,"
         "OtherThing.timestamp >= now - 60)"
     )



class OtherThing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'others'

    ...
    thing_id = sa.Column('thing_id', sa.Integer, nullable=False)
    timestamp = sa.Column('timestamp', sa.DateTime)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I've also tried `>= remote('now - 60')` and a few other variations. Each fails with various exceptions.

How do I correctly setup this query to do what I want? I found a result suggesting the `ADDDATE` function, but it appears that's not part of sqlalchemy anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try using func.now() in your expression instead of now:

```
recent_things = sa.orm.relationship(
    'OtherThing', primaryjoin="and(MyThing.id==OtherThing.thing_id,"
    "OtherThing.timestamp >= func.now() - 60)"
)
```

Here is the doc page for func: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.func